# regular expression for finding and replacing variable URL strings in XML

Tags: xml, regex, url, dreamweaver

I'm having some difficulty figuring out a regular expression for stripping part of the string within a particular XML tag and replacing it. I have a number of URL paths with variable parts, so I need to find everything between a certain string and the last slash in the URL. For example, I might have tags and URLS that look like this:

> `<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/images/I//1951-1960_Embark_Object_Photos/1957.59.jpg</bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>`

or

> `<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/images/CONTEMPORARY/1986-2005/1991.2.jpg</bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>`

The output should look like

> `<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/Previews/1957.59.jpg</bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>`

This is about as far as I got, but it captures the last slash in the string, and not the second-to-last slash:

> `(<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/images)+(.*[/])`

That regex will capture the following:

> `<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/images/I//1951-1960_Embark_Object_Photos/1957.59.jpg</`

What would I need to add to the regex to exclude the `</bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>` bit from the query and then capture everything prior to the last slash in the URL?

Comment: +1 for a well-posed regex question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is XML, there can't be a (non-escaped) `<` or `>` in the URL itself. You can use this to your advantage:

```
<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/images[^<]*/([^<]*)
```

This should capture the last segment (e.g. "1957.59.jpg") of the URL. It works by greedily matching everything up to the start of the end-of-tag (the first `[^<]*`), then backtracking to match the nearest (i.e. last) `/`, then capturing everything after that slash (the `([^<]*)`) into group 1 so that you can use it during the replacement step.

Comment: Hi @Cameron: Thanks so much for your response! You're my personal hero for the day. Since the replacement string is consistent, I ended up with the following: FIND: <bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/images[^<]*/</br>

replace with:

<bpoc:resourceMetadataLoc>http://app01/media/Previews

Comment: @Isara: No problem :-) Side tip: You can surround the URLs in your comment with backticks to give them code-formatting so they aren't auto-converted into links.

Comment: clearly I'm not a coder. Markdown and regex makes my head hurt! ;)